# Wrap rclcpp::Node with basic Lifecycle behavior?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a system built leveraging multiple rclcpp::Lifecycle nodes for managing system lifecycle. I would like to include an external non-lifecycle node in this system, but ideally allow it to be controlled through the same management mechanisms. Is there any ROS2 tool out there which can wrap an existing rclcpp::Node with a basic lifecycle behavior. For example maybe the node doesn't actually launch at all until the active state is hit? I think as it stands now having a non-lifecycle node in your system seems to immediately degrade the system to a non-lifecycle compliant state.

Edit: My current plan is to write my own ComponentManager (based of the rclcpp implementation) which is a lifecycle node and will defer node loading until activate is called. When deactivate is called it would unload the nodes. While obviously not very efficient I think this will enforce the minimal portion of the lifecycle behavior (preventing interactions with other nodes when not ACTIVE) as well as supporting shutdown behavior. I will post here if this works, unless someone shares a better solution first.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390754/wrap-rclcpp::node-with-basic-lifecycle-behavior?/) by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2021-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems the approach I described in my "Edit:" does work. I think I will probably try to upstream this for others and I have posted as such on ROS Discourse.
https://discourse.ros.org/t/launch-wrapper-for-rclcpp-node-to-make-it-a-lifecyclenode/23106

---

Originally posted by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) with karma: 268 on 2021-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0